# Drawing a modifiable diagram

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to draw a diagram like the image below and would like to know if there is a more efficient way to doing this in XML. Below is my unfinished code but I want to hear suggestions and examples from others please. I want to also be able to copy and modify the code at a later stage & I want the diagram to look right on all devices (i.e. suitable margins, padding, etc.) All helpful replies would be very much appreciated.

[image: diagram]

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/colored_bar"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/central"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/car_separator0"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/car_separator1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/car_separator2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/black" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:layout_weight=".25" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:padding="1.5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/central"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As a general rule you should try to not overload your xml with views, it's not performing very well, so writing custom view here is the best and most flexible solution

Comment: OK so how I go about creating this using a custom view?

Comment: can't help more than google: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend not drawing this in xml. Instead, this is a perfect use for a custom view. It should be fairly easy to get drawing. For example, the little boxes can simply, and quickly be drawn in a for loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < canvasWidth; y+=yStride) {
  canvas.drawRect(littleRect, paint);
}
```

Really, the biggest pain about drawing this by hand would be touch IO, but even then that isn't too bad.

Comment: What did you mean by 'IO'?

Comment: User's touch input. The 'O' was added just as habit.

Comment: Is it possible to declare a canvas element in XML and then add some java code to specify what to draw within the canvas?

Comment: @user3293579 Sorry, it is not. You will need to extend and implement your own view class. However, once that class is implemented, you may declare it in xml. This is one of the tutorials I used to get more familiar with implementing custom views. IT's not at all what you are trying to do, but it does teach the premise of defining and using a custom view. http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Comment: Can this be done by putting all the shapes in one set of dimensions only (width x height) and scaling it according to the device screen?

Comment: Are there any other useful samples out there?

Comment: To your first question, if you are asking if you can calculate the graphic dimensions using height and width instead of scaling the canvas, then yes. As for samples, I'm sure of it. I just found that one most helpful to me. What are you missing from it?

Comment: Basically finding a way to make the big grey rectangles equal in size based on the number of them there are.